# for-loop runs too slowly

Tags: r, for-loop

I write a piece of R code, but as I am not an expert, I feel that my code is not optimal and so long to process...
How can I improve this code?

here is the code:

```
for (k in 1 : length(df_3L)) {
    vec <- c()
    for(i in 1 : dim(df_3L[[k]])[1]) {
        for(j in 1 : dim(df_3L[[k]])[1] - 1) {
            if (df_3L[[k]][i] == df_3L[[k]][j + 1]) {
                vec <- c(vec, 1)
            } else {
                vec <- c(vec, 0)
            }
        }
    }
    assign(paste0("vec_3L", k), vec)
}
```

for more details, the `k` in the for-loop is the number of subjects (40) ; the `df_3L` files are vectors with 500 rows.

Comment: Please provide some [MCVE], perhaps even with some input (or some hand-made random data). So **edit your question** to improve it

Comment: I’ve taken the liberty of formatting your code to make it minimally readable.

Comment: thank you for your comments

Comment: In order to provide a fully reproductible example, could you add the result of `dput(df_3kL) ` (or, if too long, at least of `dput(head(df_3kL))`) ?

Comment: I’m confused by the close votes. Surely it’s absolutely clear what the question here is (for anybody who knows R), and it’s perfectly on topic?! @BasileStarynkevitch etc.

Comment: The close votes are because you don't show any [MCVE], something which we could copy&paste, then run.

Comment: I ran your proposed command to give you more information about my data, but the output is to long provide it on this page.

Comment: I thought this platform was also there to help us for debugging codes ... but apparently this type of question are not welcome ... too bad ...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That seems like unthinking application of the text of the law, rather than its intent. The example is actually completely 
sufficient to see the problem in this instance.

Answer (score 3):

Your code runs slowly because you are growing a vector inside a loop. This is a typical performance anti-pattern, see for instance [this article by Andrew Barr](http://www.ancienteco.com/2013/11/faster-for-loops-in-r.html), amongst countless others.

The solution is to (1) either preallocate your vector and assign a value at a specific index, or (2) forego the loop and create the vector using list functions (such as `lapply`). In your case that’s made harder (though not impossible) due to the nested loops. Variant (1) is therefore a bit easier to perform out of the box:

Replace

```
vec <- c()
```

with

```
vec = vector("numeric", dim(df_3kL[[k]])[1] * (dim(df_3kL[[k]])[1] - 1))
```

And replace the whole inner loop `if` with

```
vec[i] = if (df_3kL[[k]][i] == df_3kL[[k]][j + 1]) 1 else 0
```

Now, this isn’t *good* code. Improving it by vectorisation is left as an exercise to the reader.

Also, you can make your code immediately readable by being *consistent*: don’t mix styles (such as `<-` vs `=` assignment, `seq` vs `:` …) mid-code.

Comment: tkanks, I'll try. Do you have any example to provide me?

Comment: Yes, thanks for your advice about my code. I will be more consistent.

Comment: @Konrad Have you profiled this? I believe the JIT compiler should take care of the growing vectors issue (and didn't the NEWS say that R now has limited over-allocation for vectors?). I think the problem might be rather (a) the many R function calls and (b) creating (allocating) many separate objects with `assign`.

Comment: @Roland “I believe the JIT compiler should take care of the growing vectors issue” — and how would it do that?! As for over-allocating, R has traditionally not done this; it would be a boon if it now did; pre-allocating would still be more efficient though. Anyway, I agree that there’s a lot more to be done. I was picking off the low-hanging fruits, which is the hot loop.

Comment: See [the NEWS](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/doc/NEWS.Rd#L1229) regarding (limited) over-allocation.

Comment: @Roland Good news indeed (I must have already read this and forgotten about it). Nevertheless, growing a vector is still slower than pre-allocating it and, depending on the growth factor, potentially even *asymptotically* slower.

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs slowly because you are performing tight inner loops instead of relying on vectorized functions.

Timing the original implementation using simulated data shows that it is slow indeed:

```
df_3L <- replicate(10, matrix(runif(200), nrow = 200), simplify = FALSE)

system.time({
    for (k in 1 : length(df_3L)) {
        vec <- c()
        for(i in 1 : dim(df_3L[[k]])[1]) {
            for(j in 1 : dim(df_3L[[k]])[1] - 1) {
                if (df_3L[[k]][i] == df_3L[[k]][j + 1]) {
                    vec <- c(vec, 1)
                } else {
                    vec <- c(vec, 0)
                }
            }
        }
        assign(paste0("vec_3L", k), vec)
    }
})
 ##   user  system elapsed 
 ## 21.270   0.008  21.599
```

Anytime you see `if .. else` inside a `for` loop in R you can be sure it is going to be dog slow. The solution is to recognize that we can do the comparisons all at once rather than one at a time. This allows us to get rid of the entire inner-most loop, and speed up the code dramatically:

```
system.time({
    for (k in 1 : length(df_3L)) {
        vec <- c()
        for(i in 1 : dim(df_3L[[k]])[1]) {
            vec <- c(vec, as.numeric(df_3L[[k]][i] == df_3L[[k]]))
        }
        assign(paste0("vec_3L", k), vec)
    }
})

##  user  system elapsed 
## 0.114   0.000   0.114
```

In fact we don't even need the `i` loop, and for convenience we can use `lapply` in place of the `k` loop. A final idiomatic and fast implementation might look like this:

```
system.time({
    vecs <- lapply(df_3L, function(x) {
        x <- x[, 1]
        as.numeric(do.call(`==`, expand.grid(x, x)))
    })
})
##  user  system elapsed 
## 0.016   0.000   0.016
```